# 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

[image]

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            //try
            //{
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Email Address] FROM [Staff] WHERE [Access Level]='Manager'", con);
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdr.Read())
                {

                    string emailaddress = Convert.ToString(sdr["Email Address"]);


                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("possystemmahdealjamil@gmail.com");
                    mail.To.Add(emailaddress);
                    mail.Subject = "Todays POS System Reports";
                    mail.Body = "Todays shift is closed at"+DateTime.Now.ToString();

                    smtpServer.Port = 587;
                    smtpServer.Credentials = new [enter image description here][1]System.Net.NetworkCredential("possystemmahdealjamil@gmail.com", @"###########");
                    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpServer.Send(mail);

                    MessageBox.Show("Mail is Send Successfully ", "Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "open shift failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //}
            //finally
            //{
            //    con.Close();
            //}
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem is solved, there was Security Settings Issue, for this i had to give access to the less secure app option on my sender email

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65592585/15054795) solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced the same problem. Although I had given access to less secure app on my sender email, the problem was still not resolved. After a thorough searching and trial & error, I've changed the password of my sender email to a new one which is way stronger than the previous one. And voila! the problem was resolved.

What was really confusing that, this kind of error for weaker password usually comes with a code 5.5.1. like this:
`The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.  The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required`

This may occur if the existing password does not meet the email host's password requirements. But for me the error code was 5.7.0.